# marshal and unmarshal with CXF

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

in my server when a client attempt to access to my webservice i get this error

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: hibernate.SBaraque is not known to this context
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:619)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    ... 42 more
```

this error show when my client try to call this methode :

```java
@WebResult(name="listes")
public List findByPropery(@WebParam(name="arg1") String arg1, @WebParam(name="Value1") Object Value1);
```

which call the DAO class

```java
public List findByPropery(String arg1, Object Value1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("findByPropery DAO IN");

    return getSession().createQuery("from SBaraque where "+arg1+" = ?").setParameter(0, Value1).list();
}
```

this is my interface :

```java
@WebService
public interface InterfaceService  {
    public void save(@WebParam(name="object") Object obj);

    public void modify(@WebParam(name="object") Object obj);

    public void delete(@WebParam(name="object") Object obj);

    @WebResult(name="listes")
    public List findAll();

    @WebResult(name="object")
    public Object findById (@WebParam(name="id") Integer id);   

    @WebResult(name="listes")
    public List findByListPropery(@WebParam(name="arg1") String arg1,
            @WebParam(name="Value1") Object Value1,
            @WebParam(name="arg2") String arg2,
            @WebParam(name="Value2") Object Value2);

    @WebResult(name="listes")
    public List findByPropery(@WebParam(name="arg1") String arg1,
            @WebParam(name="Value1") Object Value1);

    @WebResult(name="listes")
    public List findBySQLRequest(@WebParam(name="request") String request);

    @WebResult(name="listes")
    public List findByHQLRequest(@WebParam(name="request") String request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add a @XmlSeeAlso annotation that would point to all the possible classes that the service would accept and return.  Otherwise, JAXB would not know anything about them.